# MapboxGL JS / Maplibre GL - Use image from sprite in HTML <img> tag

Tags: sprite, mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

For my web map I have a sprite including multiple icons. I built a legend based on HTML div-elements and I would like to include some of the icons from the sprite in a simple img-tag like this:

```
<img src="icon-from-sprite"/>
```

My sprite is accessible via `https://url/sprites/mysprite.png` and `https://url/sprites/mysprite.json`. It works to include the whole sprite as an image using:

```
<img src="https://url/sprites/mysprite.png"/>
```

But how can I access a certain icon from within my sprite? Is this possible at all?